# Set home page to last page of a certain category

Tags: homepage

I want to create a new website with reversed pagination (I mean latest post is found in last page , while oldest one is found in first page)
I could do that already with "Default Sort Ascend" plugin.

Now what I want is to set front page to be the last page of a specific category (even with redirection) ... ANY HELP ??

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `per_get_posts` filter hook to change the order of the query something like:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_homepage_posts_order');
function filter_homepage_posts_order($query) {
    //only run is current page is home page
    if ($query->is_home) {
        $limit_number_of_posts = 5; //number of posts 
        $featured_category_id = get_cat_id('Reviews'); // by cat name...
        $query->set('cat', $featured_category_id);
        $query->set('posts_per_page', $limit_number_of_posts);
        $query->set('order','DESC')
    }
  return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It really shows last posts from that category ,but without pagination reversed also the menu bar now shows my other pages (not my custom links) ! 
I'm ok with showing posts from a specific category, what I want is to either direct homepage to last page of that category or reverse its pagination so that last page shows newst post while first page shows OLDEST post.

Comment: What ??? it works? not Working?

Comment: sorry, comment got disturped :) I re-edited it

Comment: about reversed pagination , as I said before that I used a plugin to revese posts query so my NEWEST post is shown in last page, but when I enter this category it shows page one which displayes the oldest post :(  I hop you understand me !